# Failed to resolve import "vue-router" from "src/router/index..js". Does the file exist?

Tags: vue.js

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Page1 from '../components/Page1.vue'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
 name: 'Page1',
      component: Page1
    },
    {
      path: '/Page2',
      name: 'Page2',
      component: () => import('../components/Page2.vue')
    },
  ]
})
export default router
```

import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
我要如何去修改'vue-router'這個錯誤

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's unknown what's your setup. It could be wrong, or there's no vue-router package installed] as the error implies

Comment: 是我自己沒有 npm install vue-router,謝謝

Comment: according to google translate, the issue is resolved now that they installed vue-router...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.